# How can I add my application in airdrop share extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

In this image when I share notes via `AirDrop` than doesn't show me my application in `AirDrop` share via application,
just like Whatsapp,Facebook.

How can I apply share extension in my application in `AirDrop`?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to your need you need to create specific type of Extension.

Check [Types of App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/) and https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/ for various types of extension types.

Follow below tutorial to create one:

[in Swift](http://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/)

[in Objective-C](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794)

Comment: Thanks for the link.